# Password verifying against database using bcrypt

Tags: php

Im trying to verify a password against the one in the database but it doesn't work.
Please see my code and let me know what's wrong.

Code for storing username and password to the database.

```
<?php

echo "enter the username \n";

$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "enter the password\n";

$password = trim(fgets(STDIN));

//connecting to database

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata","accounts");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);

$hashedPassword= crypt($password , '$2y$10$' . $salt);

echo $hashedPassword;

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (username, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPassword')");

mysqli_close($con)

?>
```

Code for verifying password is as follows

```
<?php


echo "enter the username \n";

$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "enter the password\n";

$password = trim(fgets(STDIN));

//connecting to database

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata") or die(mysql_error());


//selecting our database

$db_select = mysql_select_db("accounts", $db) or die(mysql_error());

$result= mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$username' ");

if ( !$result ) exit( "$userName wasn't found in the database!" );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

$storedPassword = $row['password'];

$salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);

$hashedPassword= crypt($password , '$2y$10$' . $salt);

if (crypt($hashedPassword) == $storedPassword)
{
echo "ok";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you save you password to the database you are using:

```
$hashedPassword= crypt($password , '$2y$10$' . $salt);
```

but when you retrieve the password and check it I see a couple of things wrong:

```
$storedPassword = $row['password'];

$salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);

$hashedPassword= crypt($password , '$2y$10$' . $salt);

if (crypt($hashedPassword) == $storedPassword){/*...*/}
```

1, shouldn't:

`$hashedPassword= crypt($password, '$2y$10$' . $salt);`

be

`$hashedPassword= crypt($storedPassword, '$2y$10$' . $salt);`

2, It appears that you are using `crypt` twice:

```
$hashedPassword= crypt($password , '$2y$10$' . $salt);
if (crypt($hashedPassword) == $storedPassword)
```

so shouldn't is just be:

```
$hashedPassword= crypt($storedPassword, '$2y$10$' . $salt);
if ($hashedPassword == $storedPassword){/*...*/}
```

Comment: sorry your method doesn't work. i tried but its give me echo error $storedPassword = $row['password'];

$salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);


$hashpassword = crypt ($storedPassword, '$2y$10$' . $salt);
if ($hashpassword == $storedPassword)
{
echo "ok";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than you are thinking. The crypt format is somewhat clever: it includes the salt as the start of the crypted password, in the form (method)(salt)(hash).

When using crypt(), it only looks at (method)(salt) and uses them to return (method)(salt)(hash), so to *verify* a password, all you need to do is pass the crypted password as the salt and see if the result matches. That is to say,

```
crypt($testPassword, $hashedPassword) === $hashedPassword
```

Comment: thank you it work with `crypt($testPassword, $hashedPassword) === $hashedPassword`